# Change of Variables for probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)\rightarrow(S,\mathcal{S})$
be a measurable map. Let $g:(S,\mathcal{S})\rightarrow(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$
be a measurable real-valued function. Let $A\in\mathcal{F}$ (an event). I am trying to see how to properly represent the integral
$$\int_{A}g(X(\omega))\, dP(\omega)$$
as an integral over $S$ (Since $X$ maps from $A$ while $g$ maps from $S$. Of course, this is under the usual assumptions of these integrals (non-negativity or finite integral).Furthermore, how do you express the new transformed measure in terms of $P$,$A$ and$X$ exclusively?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $\mu(B)=P(\{X\in B\}\cap A)$ for all $B\in \mathcal S$. Can you show that 
$$\int_Ag(X(\omega))dP(\omega)=\int_Sg(y)\mu(dy)$$
using the three/four steps in the construction of the abstract integral?

Comment: +1. I was thinking that OP wanted this change of variables formula with $\mu =PX^{-1}$ .